# I would like to find the game with the most sales in north america for the year it was released

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The tables**

```
create table genre(
genre_id int primary key,
name varchar(50));

create table game(
game_id int primary key,
name varchar(1000),
genre_id int foreign key references genre(genre_id)); 

create table publisher(
publisher_id int primary key,
name varchar(50));

create table game_publisher(
gpub_id int primary key,
game_id int foreign key references game(game_id),
publisher_id int foreign key references publisher(publisher_id));

create table platform(
platform_id int primary key,
name varchar(50));

create table game_platform(
gplat_id int primary key,
release_year int,
gpub_id int foreign key references game_publisher(gpub_id),
platform_id int foreign key references platform(platform_id));

create table region(
region_id int primary key,
name varchar(50));

create table region_sales(
region_id int foreign key references region(region_id),
gplat_id int foreign key references game_platform(gplat_id),
num_sales decimal(5,2));
```

**The query I currently have.
Its giving me the name, number of sales, and the release year for each game but I only want the 1 game with the most sale in north america for that year it was released in.  **

```
select gp.release_year, g.name AS game_name, rs.num_sales, r.name AS region_name
from game g inner join game_publisher gpub ON g.game_id = gpub.game_id
inner join game_platform gp ON gpub.gpub_id = gp.gpub_id
inner join region_sales rs ON gp.gplat_id = rs.gplat_id
inner join region r ON rs.region_id = r.region_id
where r.name = 'north America' 
group by gp.release_year, g.name, r.name, rs.num_sales
order by rs.num_sales desc;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide `INSERT` statements for sample data and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Also tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model doesn't have enough information to answer this question, because `sales` does not have a date in it.

If there were a "year" column -- or any date at all -- you could use that in the query.  Then the idea is to `order by` and select one row.

```
select gp.release_year, g.name AS game_name, rs.num_sales, r.name AS region_name
from game g inner join
     game_publisher gpub
     on g.game_id = gpub.game_id inner join
     game_platform gp 
     on gpub.gpub_id = gp.gpub_id inner join
     region_sales rs 
     on gp.gplat_id = rs.gplat_id inner join
     region r 
     on rs.region_id = r.region_id
where r.name = 'North America' and
      gp.release_year = s.sales_year
order by rs.num_sales desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support the standard `fetch first` clause, so you might need `select top`, `limit` or some other construct.

If there is one row per year of region sales, then no aggregation is needed.  However, if there are multiple rows, then you would need aggregation.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, i was thinking that the sales table would need a date as well but i wasn't to sure!